# Is it okay to instantiate a new random_distribution every time?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I have a static `std::default_random_engine` seeded with `std::random_device` when the program launches.

Now I want to generate random numbers using that random engine so I do:

`std::uniform_int_distribution<std::default_random_engine::result_type> dist{min, max};`

to create a distribution. This distribution has a fixed range. I have no way of changing the range to say `[min2, max2]`.. so instead I create a new distribution.

Is it okay to keep creating these objects? For example:

```
int generate_random(int min, int max)
{
    //creates a new distribution every time..
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::default_random_engine::result_type> dist(min, max);
    return dist(engine);
};
```

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it okay to instantiate a new random_distribution every time?

In general, no.  However for `uniform_int_distribution`, yes.

Here's the deal:  Some distributions maintain more state than simply the parameters you construct it with.  And it is not easy to know which distributions do this and which don't.

An implementation of `uniform_int_distribution` will simply store the range you construct it with, and then use that range on each call of the distribution with an engine.

*However* a `normal_distribution` *might* store more state than simply what it is constructed with.  As you call it with an engine it *might* compute more than one result at a time (for performance reasons), give you one, and then cache the other.  When you call it a second time, it simply hands you the cached result.  For example the [Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) technique generates two results with each "call".

So it really depends on the distribution, and the implementation of that distribution.

However there's an out...

Each distribution has a nested `param_type`, and an auxiliary call operator that takes one.  You can use this to *efficiently* give your distribution new construction parameters without risking throwing away state in your distribution.  For example:

```
int generate_random(int min, int max)
{
    using Dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::default_random_engine::result_type>;
    static Dist dist(min, max);
    return dist(engine, Dist::param_type(min, max));
};
```

So now you don't have to sweat whether or not your distribution is caching results.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. I read somewhere about the caching and that's why I was worried that creating it was bad. Lucky thing I asked :D!

Thanks!!!